# Combinatorial problem- Parallel Electric Circuit with 8 independent switches

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability, intuition, independence

This is the electric circuit in our problem:
[image: Electric Circuit]

It has 4 parallel connections. There are 8 switches that are independent.
Each of the switches is closed in probability of 0.7, and then the electric current can go by the switch.
The questions are:

1. What is the probability that electric current will go from A to B?
2. It is now known that there are exactly 5 switches open in the 3 bottom branches. What is the probability now that the electric current will flow from A to B?
3. Now there are exactly 5 switches open in the electric curcuit. What is the probability that the electric current will flow from A to B?

I have trouble building the correct logical intuition to solve the problem.
If we are talking about A- the probabilty for switch 1 and switch 2 will both be closed (and then the electric current will go from A to b) is $0.7\times0.7$  and it is equal for the probability that switch 1 and switch 3 will both be close but then the electric current won`t be able to go to B.
How do I sepearate between the cases? Meaning between that the electric current will go from A to B and would not go. As you see it has the same probability.
When I solve it, how can I promise that only the switches I want will be closed?

Edit- So Q1 we solve with Binomic disturbution. Can I solve Q2 and Q3 by it as well?

Comment: Looking at question 1) you can think of $4$ independent events that have equal probability to succeed or fail. There will be electric current if at least one of the experiments succeeds. This can be solved with binomial distribution having parameters $n=4$ and $p=0.7^2$. It is handsome to find the probability that none of the experiments succeed.

Comment: Thanks, what are the number of succeses? 1, right?

Comment: If $S$ denotes this number of successes then it is a random variable that can take the values $0,1,2,3,4$ and has binomial distribution as described in my former comment. Then you must find $P(S\geq1)$ which equals $1-P(S=0)$. A succes corresponds with a closed parallel connection. For instance if the switches 3 and 4 are closed then there is a success.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I assume that for question 2 and 3, I cannot use the binomic distrubution. To solve it I need to use pure combanitorics?

Comment: In question 2) it is indirectly stated that *only* combination 1,2 can result in a success. So there you must just find the probability on that specific success.

Comment: Can we solve it by binomic that the trials n will be 2, P will be 0.49, and succeses will be 1?

Comment: I think only one trial. If 5 switches are open among the switches 3,4,5,6,7,8 then only the upper connection (with switches 1 and 2) can be closed. The probability on that is $0.7^2$. Here I stop commenting. Good luck.